# How can I find BlendShape in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to get BlendShape by writing the following program, but I couldn't get it.

How can I get BlendShape in Unity?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class unityRecieve : MonoBehaviour
{

    private SkinnedMeshRenderer meshTarget;

    // Start is called 
    void Start()
    {
        meshTarget = GameObject.Find("BlendShapes").GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an object
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the name of your gameobject first. In your screenshot, gameobjects have their names listed in the left panel.